# Case statement in where clause in SQL Server if variable have any value otherwise compare current

Tags: sql-server, case, where-clause, clause

I have 2 tables `Account` and `Roles`. I want to get all users whether they have any role or not. But when I run below query it returns only users which have any role in the `Roles` tables, but it does not return users which don't have any role.

I'm checking if there is any value in @role_id variable then it compare with @role_id otherwise compare with current value. Is it correct?

```
SELECT 
    a.user_id, a.username, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.division_id,   
    a.dept_id, a.email, a.password, a.IsAdmin, a.status, a.cdate, a.mdate 
FROM 
    Account AS a 
LEFT JOIN 
    Roles r ON a.user_id = r.user_id
WHERE 
    r.role_id = (CASE 
       WHEN @role_id IS NOT NULL AND @role_id <> '' THEN @role_id ELSE r.role_id 
    END)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.username, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.division_id, a.dept_id, a.email,
a.password, a.IsAdmin, a.status, a.cdate, a.mdate FROM Account AS a 
LEFT JOIN Roles r on a.user_id = r.user_id
WHERE ((ISNULL(@role_id,'') = '') OR (r.role_id = @role_id))
```

Comment: Thanks @Amc. There are multiple user roles in the Roles table and I just added group by clause with your solution and it works like a dream for me. Great...

Comment: SELECT a.user_id, a.username, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.division_id, a.dept_id, a.email,
a.password, a.IsAdmin, a.status, a.cdate, a.mdate FROM Account AS a 
LEFT JOIN UserSiteRoles r on a.user_id = r.user_id
WHERE ((ISNULL(@role_id,'') = '') OR (r.role_id = @role_id))-- AND ((ISNULL(@site_id,'') = '') OR (r.site_id = @site_id))
GROUP BY a.user_id, a.username, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.division_id, a.dept_id, a.email,
a.password, a.IsAdmin, a.status, a.cdate, a.mdate

Answer (score 0):

Careful when puting conditions on your `WHERE` when they are optional, they should be as an additional condition on your `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
    a.user_id, a.username, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.division_id,   
    a.dept_id, a.email, a.password, a.IsAdmin, a.status, a.cdate, a.mdate 
FROM 
    Account AS a 
LEFT JOIN 
    Roles r ON a.user_id = r.user_id
AND 
    (@role_id IS NULL OR @role_id = r.role_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the condition in join (`ON`), in order to get all results from Account table even if results dont match with Roles one.

```
SELECT 
    a.user_id, a.username, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.division_id,   
    a.dept_id, a.email, a.password, a.IsAdmin, a.status, a.cdate, a.mdate 
FROM 
    Account AS a 
LEFT JOIN 
    Roles r ON a.user_id = r.user_id
               and
               r.role_id = (
               CASE 
                    WHEN ISNULL(@role_id, '') = '' THEN r.role_id
               ELSE @role_id
               END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a LEFT OUTER JOIN here:

```
SELECT 
    a.user_id, a.username, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.division_id, 
    a.dept_id, a.email, a.password, a.IsAdmin, a.status, a.cdate, a.mdate, CASE WHEN r.user_id IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS HAS_ROLE 
FROM 
    Account AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Roles r ON a.user_id = r.user_id
```